# Is there a method only retrieve location coordinates when there is a change

Tags: codenameone

Following methods are used to start and stop location tracking using my App to poll the location continuously almost every minute. I would like to capture the location only when there is a change in coordinates. I'm wondering there is any method that would do comparison and retrieve location when there is a change.
I have tried to manually compare the coordinates which is making the requests slow down. Please advise.

```
public void stopTracking() {
        if (time != null) {
            time.cancel();
        }
        time = null;
        LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener(null);
    }

    public void startTracking() {
        if (time != null) {
            stopTracking();
        }
        if (Preferences.get("LocationTracking", true)) {
            long delay = Server.instance.getLoctionPollingIntervalMillis();
            LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener(this,
                    new LocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_ACCUARCY, delay));
            time = new Timer();
            time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (lastLocation != null) {
                        double lat = (double) lastLocation.getLatitude();
                        double lot = (double) lastLocation.getLongitude();
                        Server.instance.updateLocationInServer(lat, lot, System.currentTimeMillis(), true);
                    }
                }
            }, 30000, delay);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the timer code and write the server update in the `LocationRequest` class which is invoked by the listener. I'd also suggest adding an update threshold as some implementations can update you on a very high frequency and on movement that's very fine.

Comment: Shai, I need timer and with condition that location should be polled when there is a change. Can  you provide any example please.

Comment: There are several examples here https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/location/LocationManager.html